# Copy ESRI Map by Value (not Reference) in JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Any way that you know of in JavaScript to copy an ESRI map object by value, not by reference?

I know that I can do this:

```
var foo = new esri.Map("foo");
var bar = foo;
foo.id; //"foo"
bar.id; //"foo"
foo.id = "oof";
bar.id; //"oof"
```

what I want is to make a copy of foo so that

```
bar.id = "bar";
foo.id; //"foo"
bar.id; //"bar"
```

Any ideas? So far the best I've come up with to to construct two different maps, and then copy foo's graphics, features, etc over to bar:

```
var foo = new esri.Map("foo");
//do some stuff to foo, adding layers etc
var bar = new esri.Map("bar");
bar.addLayers(foo.getLayersVisibleAtScale());
//etc
```

Comment: Have you tried using dojo's [clone](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-clone)?

Comment: `dojo.clone(map);`
`//TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

Comment: Also tried:
`var foobar = $.extend(true, {}, map);  //RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`